# Osmdroid Cache manager doesn't work

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using osmdroid and osmdroid bonus back and i can't cache my tiles for offline use.
I followed this url: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Cache-Manager

This is the code that i use to cache tiles,

CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(map);
BoundingBox bbox = new BoundingBox(33.298190, -8.572239, 33.148845, -8.393711);
cacheManager.downloadAreaAsync(getActivity(), bbox, 10, 15);

I don't know if i did it in the wrong way but when i run my project, my tiles are not downloaded, and the progressbar shows on for 2 secends and disappears with any error message.

I seek any help?

Comment: I resolved my issue, it was due to an invalid Bounding box, i'v had to inverse the two points that represents the bounding box,